# Java - expression must be an array type but it resolved to Stack<String>

Tags: java

I am making a program where I declared a Stack and named it "words". I used this code, like so:

```
Stack <String> words = new Stack<String>();
```

but when I tried to use this code to shuffle the words in it, an error about it being a stack appears:

```
Collections.shuffle(words);
int mistakes = 0;
final String CORRECT_WORD= words[0];
```

how can i resolve this error?

Comment: What is the concrete error? You should provide the error msg, otherwise we have to figure that out...

Comment: @tuergeist The error is in the title.

Comment: @Code-Guru: Ehm. Yes. ok... it was too obviuos for me :)

Comment: @tuergeist I know the feeling ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need the first value from `words`, just use `pop()`:

```
final String CORRECT_WORD = words.pop();
```

or `Vector`'s `elementAt(0)`.

```
final String CORRECT_WORD = words.elementAt(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
final String CORRECT_WORD= words[0];
```

Java Collections do not support array syntax like the C++ equivalents do. Instead, you must use methods from the API. In this case, you need to use `[Stack.pop()][1]`:

```
final String CORRECT_WORD= words.pop();
```

The [Java API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) are a very useful tool which will tell you what methods are available for each interface and class. Since you are using the Stack class, you should certainly familiarize yourself with the [docs for Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

Comment: shouldn't it be Pop() ? The OP isn't talking about a List?

Comment: @Thousand yes, it should be `pop()`. I submitted my answer quickly then went back to edit after I checked the API docs.

Answer (score 2):

A stack is designed to only let you access the last element added (i.e. it's a LIFO, Last-In-First-Out), which makes shuffling problematic.

If you want to shuffle the words, put them into a List (such as an ArrayList), shuffle them, then put them onto a stack or queue once they've been shuffled.

Comment: Since `Stack` implements `List` and `Collection.shuffle()` accepts `List` parameters, it is probably a good assumption that the API authors have dealt with the "problematic" parts of shuffling a LIFO structure. Of course, anyone going back to read this might be confused, depending on the context.